# Python script stuck in infinite loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a beginner python script for the python challenge ARG. The basic aim is to write a script that will read through a mass of text, pass through only the lower-case characters with exactly 3 capitals either side. The script is supposed to look at an incoming character from a list, store the next 3 characters and previous 3 characters in a list. Once this has happened, the script evaluates whether or not the incoming character is a capital, if it is the loop starts over, if not the script then evaluates if all three characters in the list are capitalised. If the conditions are met, the script should print the current character, else the loops starts over.

Whenever I run this script I am left with no debug/error/warnings about the code but it never completes or writes anything to the file.

here is the code I have written, any help would be appreciated.

```
#code, where f = text to be processed, d = text file to be written to

f = open("test.txt", "r+")
f = f.read()
fList = list(f)
limit = len(fList)

#Set location of result
d = open("noided.txt", "r+")
i, j, k = [0, 0, 0]

#Main loop
#While there are characters left to be processed
while i < limit:
    #Skip the first 4 characters
    if i < 4:
        #print i, fList[i]
        i += 1
    else:
        #print i, fList[i]
        currentChar = fList[i]
        count = 0
        prevChars = [fList[i-1],fList[i-2],fList[i-3]]
        nextChars = fList[i:i + 3]

        if currentChar.isupper():

            i += 1

        else:
            while k < 3:
                if prevChars[k].isupper() and nextChars[k].isupper():
                    count += 1
                    k += 1
                elif count == 3:
                    print currentChar
                    d.write(currentChar)
                    i += 1
                else:
                    i += 1
```

Comment: Where are the variables `i`, `limit` and `k` initialized? It also looks like the indentation of the code is not correct

Comment: Please fix your indentation. The `else` probably belongs to the `if`, not to the `while` (also possible, but less likely in this context). Also, `&` is bitwise-and; while it works, here, too, you probably want `and` instead.

Comment: That was my bad on the indentation, didn't notice it but wasn't like that in my editor, to answer the first question, yes every variable has been initialised, just not shown here as I thought it was pointless to show.

Comment: You should post some example input and output to help us understand what exactly your program is supposed to do.

Comment: ok give me one moment and ill add all of my code.

Comment: FYI the goal of that challenge is to use the `re` module.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks, I'm reading up on Regular expressions now, this seems much more logical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you have no variable named limit. Second, it would be easier to use stack type of list. Think of the stack as a stack of papers. You can parse the letters from the file into the stack (using a for loop), but then you can compare each character before it enters the stack, making this module useful for this kind of project